# Accessing multiple ADC channels value inside the timer interrupt

Tags: stm32, adc

I am using a STM32-G07 board to receive adc values. There are two channels which I have already configured but since the adc configuration is connected to the external trigger which is timer interrupt 2 in the MCU, as I try to switch the channels, the interrupt stops working.

part of the whole code:

```
    void ADC_Select_CH0 (void)
{
    ADC_ChannelConfTypeDef sConfig = {0};
      /** Configure for the selected ADC regular channel its corresponding rank in the sequencer and its sample time.
      */
      sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_0;
      sConfig.Rank = 1;
      sConfig.SamplingTime = ADC_SAMPLINGTIME_COMMON_1;
      if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
      {
        Error_Handler();
      }
}

void ADC_Select_CH1 (void)
{
    ADC_ChannelConfTypeDef sConfig = {0};
      /** Configure for the selected ADC regular channel its corresponding rank in the sequencer and its sample time.
      */
      sConfig.Channel = ADC_CHANNEL_1;
      sConfig.Rank = 1;
      sConfig.SamplingTime = ADC_SAMPLINGTIME_COMMON_2;
      if (HAL_ADC_ConfigChannel(&hadc1, &sConfig) != HAL_OK)
      {
        Error_Handler();
      }
}
void TIM2_IRQHandler(void)
{


    if (TIM2->SR & TIM_SR_UIF)
    {
        if(adc_check == 0){
          u_adc_1 = HAL_ADC_GetValue(&hadc1);
          adc_check = 1;
        }//get adc value
        else if(adc_check == 1){
          u_adc_2 = HAL_ADC_GetValue(&hadc1);
          adc_check = 0;
        }}
int main(){
HAL_ADC_Start(&hadc1);
while (1)
    {

        if(adc_check == 0){
            ADC_Select_CH0();
//          adc_check = 1;
        }
        else if(adc_check == 1){
            ADC_Select_CH1();
//          adc_check = 0;
        }}}
```

i also tried calling the adc select function directly inside timer, but with no success. How can one select the adc channel inside the timer interrupt?

Comment: The while loop in main() will be selecting the ADC channel over and over and over again.  Is that intended?

Comment: The goal to save adc values coming from two different channels in real time inside timer interrupt. I don't know how to achieve this since we have only one ADC.